# Firebase email function not finding user

Tags: node.js, vue.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a contact form on my website that upon sending clicking to submit, runs a firebase function to execute the request. The issue i'm having all of a sudden is the following error (taken from the firebase logs)

```
Error: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:147:16)
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:513:15
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:1347:13
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

The function in charge of the sending is the following:

```
    sendRequest() {
      this.loading = true
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        const newUrl = `https://us-central1-easymediakit.cloudfunctions.net/contactForm?name=${
          this.form.name
        }&email=${this.form.email}&message=${encodeURI(
          this.form.message
        )}&uid=${this.uid}`
        fetch(`${newUrl}`, {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
          .then(() => {})
          .then(async response => {
            this.loading = false
            this.success = 'Your email has been sent.'
            resolve(response)
          })
      }).catch(error => {
        this.loading = false
        console.log('Send error', error)
      })
    }
```

It was working and I haven't made any changes to the function that handles the email sending so I'm not sure where the issue is coming from, any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Update:

in index.js

```
const contactFormModule = require('./email/email-contact-form')

exports.contactForm = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return contactFormModule.handler(req, res)
```

the contact form:

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })
const domain = 'mg.epkbuilder.com'
const apiKey = 'f27b2755b05f3a366542ea538a00c6a2-d32d817f-dec22e2e'
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({ apiKey, domain })
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const MailComposer = require('nodemailer/lib/mail-composer')

exports.handler = (req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, async () => {
    const uid = req.query.uid
    const name = req.query.name
    const email = req.query.email
    const message = req.query.message

    console.log('uid', uid)

    console.log('message', `${message}`)

    const user = await admin.auth().getUser(uid)

    console.log('user', user)

    const mailOptions = {
      from: `${name} noreply@easymediakit.io`,
      replyTo: `${name} ${email}`,
      to: user.email,
      subject: `Direct message from ${name}`,
      text: `${message}`
    }

    let mail = new MailComposer(mailOptions).compile()

    console.log('mail', mail)

    return mail.build((error, message) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Email unsuccessful', error)
        res.status(400).send(error)
      }
      const dataToSend = {
        to: user.email,
        message: message.toString('ascii')
      }
      return mailgun.messages().sendMime(dataToSend, sendError => {
        if (sendError) {
          console.log('Email unsuccessful', error)
          res.status(400).send(error)
        }
        return res.send('Email successfully sent!')
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you shared calling the Auth API, so I'm not sure if the error is coming from this code. If this is coming from the Cloud Function, can you share that code too?

Comment: I went ahead and updated the post, I'm very new to firebase functions, I also didn't write this code so it's pretty confusing for me. Is the new code that I added what you were referring to? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to come from this line:

```
const user = await admin.auth().getUser(uid)
```

The error indicates that no user exists in Firebase Authentication for the `uid` value that you specified. You might want to double check the `this.uid` value in `)}&uid=${this.uid}` in your client-side code.

Comment: okay, this makes sense, one bit of confusion is that the contact form is only input of title, email, and content. At what point is auth needed in this process? The user doesn't need to be logged in to use the contact form. Thanks again, this is helpful.